# AT-9924 - is there a way to have console commands continuous?

Tags: switch

Within the [AT-9924SP](http://www.alliedtelesis.com.au/p-1956.html) series a console command such as

```
>show config dynamic
```

displays part of the config but then prompts the console again:

```
--More--  (<space> = next page, <CR> = one line, C = continuous, Q = quit)
```

Is anyone aware of a command or config to have the console command return the entire config in the "continuous" form - from a single console command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you can only set it to be from 4 to 99 lines per page, but you can turn paging off:

```
SET TTy [History=0..99] [PAGe=4..99] [PRompt={string-15|DEFault|OFf}] [TYpe={Dumb|Vt100}] [IDLEtimeout={10..4294967294|OFF|0}]
```

> The **page** parameter sets the number of lines of command output
>   displayed on the terminal screen before the switch pauses and waits
>   for the user to press a key to continue. This number may range from 4
>   to 99. The default is 22 for both asynchronous ports and Telnet
>   connections. If **page** is set to off, paging is disabled.

To turn off paging:

> To set PAGE mode off for all subsequent Telnet connections, use the
>   command:
>
> ```
> set tt pag=of
> ```

Comment: This command works! Thank you for your help. :) The command reference is in "AlliedWare OS Software Reference - Chapter 46 Terminal Server"

Comment: More fyi for others ... the new page off config appears in the dynamic config as `# TTY configuration
set tty page=off`